# Summing the elements of two int vectors parallel to each other

Tags: c++, vector, int, addition

I'm trying to get the sum of each element of two vectors and push the total to a new vector.

ie.

a = {1, 2 ,3} & b = {1, 2 ,3}

c = a + b

c = {2, 4, 6}

I've got it working for vectors of the same size, but whenever one of the vectors is larger than the other I get a vector subscript out of range error.

a = {1, 2 ,3} & b = {1, 2 ,3, 4}

c = a + b

I'm assuming this is happening during b[3] + ?? , how would I go about adding it so the output is:

c = {2, 4, 6, 4}

What i've got so far is:

```
vector<int> a = { 1,2,3,4 };
vector<int> b = { 5,4,3,2,1 };

vector<int> *vPtr;
vPtr = new vector<int>;

int sum;
int size = a.size();
if (size < b.size())
    size = b.size();

for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum = a[i] + b[i];
    (*vPtr).push_back(sum);
}

for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = (*vPtr).begin(); it != (*vPtr).end(); it++)
    cout << *it << " ";

cout << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: pad the smaller vector with extra zeros at the end

Comment: Take out a blank piece of paper. Write down using short, brief, concise, English statements the logical step-by-step algorithm for implementing what you're trying to do. After doing that, [schedule an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposed solution, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pad the smaller vector with extra zeros at the end. Here's an example:

```
int sizeDifference = abs(a.size() - b.size());
if(sizeDifference != 0){
  if(a.size() > b.size())
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeDifference; ++i)
      b.push_back(0);
  else
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeDifference; ++i)
      a.push_back(0);
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Typically I do this with iterators in three parts. The part where both vectors have common elements. The part if/where `a` is longer than `b` and the part if/where `b` is longer than `a`.

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> b = {4, 5, 6, 7};
std::vector<int> c;

// reserve enough space for the longest vector
c.reserve(std::max(a.size(), b.size()));

auto a_itr = std::begin(a);
auto b_itr = std::begin(b);

// for the part where the positions coincide
for(; a_itr != std::end(a) && b_itr != std::end(b); ++a_itr, ++b_itr)
    c.push_back(*a_itr + *b_itr);

// for the part where a is longer than b (if any)
c.insert(std::end(c), a_itr, std::end(a));

// for the part where b is longer than a (if any)
c.insert(std::end(c), b_itr, std::end(b));

for(auto i: c)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
size_type sm_size, lg_size;
vector<int> *lg_vec_ptr;
if (a.size < b.size()) {
   sm_size = a.size();
   lg_size = b.size();
   lg_vector_ptr = &b;
} else {
   sm_size = b.size();
   lg_size = a.size();
   lg_vector_ptr = &a;
}

vector<int> *sum_vec_ptr = new vector<int>;
size_type i;
for (i=0; i<sm_size; ++i)
    sum_vec_ptr->push_back( a[i] + b[i] );
for (   ; i<lg_size; ++i)
    sum_vec_ptr->push_back( lg_vector_ptr->[i] );
```

This method doesn't modify the original vectors.